# Kotlin idiom: null-safe conditional?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

In Java, I'd write something like this:

```
if (foo != null && foo.bar()) { ...
```

However Kotlin complains that:

> Smart cast to 'Foo' is impossible, because 'foo' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

I *think* it's saying what I wrote isn't thread-safe. However, in the context where I'm using it I know it is as this will always be invoked on a single thread.

Yes `foo` needs to be mutable. I realize that making `foo` a `val` would solve this but that is not possible here.

What's the correct idiom in Kotlin to handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to use Kotlin's excellent [null-safety operators](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) to avoid having to do redundant checks.

First, we use the safe-call operator.

```
foo?.bar()
```

This is a `Boolean?` (i.e. a nullable Boolean) which is null if `foo` is null, or the result of `bar()` if not. Now, a `Boolean?` is not a valid condition in an if statement, obviously, so we need to provide a "default" value of `false`. We do that using the amusingly-named Elvis operator

```
if (foo?.bar() ?: false) { ... }
```

If `foo` is null, then `foo?.bar()` is null, and `?:` returns the value of the right-hand side, i.e. `false`. If `foo` is non-null, then `foo?.bar()` is the result of calling `bar()` on `foo`, and (assuming that result is also non-null), `?:` returns the existing non-null Boolean value.

Comment: Thank you. FYI the IDE tells me this should be replaced with `foo?.bar() == true`.

Comment: The two are equivalent. I personally disagree with the IDE on that one (when I see a comparison against Boolean, I have to really think about why it's there, whereas `?:` is more self-explanatory), but it's debatable. Don't lose too much sleep over it.

Comment: I think the IDE suggestion is less cognitive load, but it probably depends what other languages you’re accustomed to.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, a null-safe call returns a Boolean? so you can check if it equals `true`:

```
if (foo?.bar() == true) {

}
```

If you need non-null `foo` inside the conditional, then you can use the common `?.let` idiom.

```
foo?.let { foo ->
    if (foo.bar()) {
    
    }
}
```

If you know it’s only accessed on this same thread, the `!!` operator would be safe after the null check, but `?.let` is more idiomatic so easier to follow once you’re used to reading Kotlin.

Comment: I like your syntax if (foo?.bar() == true) better than the accepted answer's (foo?.bar() ?: false) XD

Answer (score 1):

In case where the condition is not just a function call, e.g.

```
foo != null && foo.bar() > 0
```

you can use `let` or `run`:

```
if (foo.let { it != null && it.bar() > 0 }) { ... }

if (foo.run { this != null && bar() > 0 }) { ... }
```